# Limit iOS app to IPv4 due to network limitations

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have an internal use only Enterprise application using Xamarin Forms and Azure App Services.

My question is how can I limit my app to only use IPv4?  Our network blocks all outgoing IPv6 traffic.  I believe this is causing issues with attempted Syncs to the Azure Backend.  I'm being told that IPv6 will continue to be blocked so I need to solve this in a different way.

Is it possible to force an app to only use IPv4?  I have seen things like [iOS - Support ipv4 only API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213601/ios-support-ipv4-only-api) but that is not the same as my issue since my Network is blocking outgoing IPv6 traffic.

Comment: Is your network assigning your device an ipv6 address? if your device has only link-local self-assigned ipv6 addresses (fe80::) then it won’t try and use ipv6 to connect to a remote host.  Have you done any network tracing or debugging to confirm that it is an ipv6 issue?

Comment: I've done what I'm capable of.  From a knowledge and access standpoint.  They were letting one be assigned but now that should be turned off so if it won't try to use the self-assigned we should be good and I'll try another round of testing.  We have a very vague issue and this was a shot in the dark.  Thanks